# IntelliJ IDEA plugin development: Get classes VirtualFile (or paths) for a specific source VirtualFile

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea

This is a cross-post from http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/message/5264436#5264436 - I failed to get any answer on that forum for two weeks now, so I'm re-asking it here (please don't flame).

This question refers to plugin development for the IntelliJ IDEA IDE, specifically targeting java development:

Is there any API to get the list of .class files for given source file?

I'm trying to write a plugin that creates a binary patch jar based on a changelist. I've managed to get the changelist and, from it, a list of source files (VirtualFile). Now I'm trying to get the compiled class files for these source files (I don't mind preforming a "make" or relying on the previous compile output).

I've played a bit with ProjectFileIndex but could only find the classes root. I'd hate to do a "dumb" path-based search because inner classes (and inner anonymous classes) would make it difficult to get correctly.

Is there such an API? Or am I doomed to parse the paths?

Thanks,
Ran.

Comment: Thanks for the question&answer - I do similar thing now and also was researching in that direction - at least now I know I can stop researching and better code the $ stuff :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around the issue by identifying classes, source root and classes root, then depending on class name conventions in Java ($1 for inner anonymous classes).